# Delete all cache with CacheEvict

Tags: java, spring, apache, caching, spring-cache

I'm using @Cacheable annotation and cacheManager it's a SimpleCacheManager. So I tried exclude all entries with @CacheEvict, there's no error but *resetProducts()* method just doesn't work.

Bean configuration

```
<bean id="cacheManager" class="org.springframework.cache.support.SimpleCacheManager">
    <property name="caches">
        <set>
            <bean class="org.springframework.cache.concurrent.ConcurrentMapCacheFactoryBean" p:name="default"/>
            <bean class="org.springframework.cache.concurrent.ConcurrentMapCacheFactoryBean" p:name="produtos"/>
        </set>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Method of ProductBO.java

```
@Cacheable(value = "produtos", key = "#id + #page + #filtros.toString() + #regiaoCep", unless = "#result == null")
public List<? extends ProdutoTO> getProdutos(String id, List<String> filtros, Integer page, String cep, String regiaoCep) {
    //Code
}
```

resetProducts

```
@Component
public class CacheConfig {

    @CacheEvict(value = "produtos", allEntries = true)
    public void resetProducts() {

    }
}
```

Action

```
public class LojaConfigAction extends GenericAction {

    @Autowired
    CacheConfig cacheConfig;

    public String eliminarCache() {
        boolean b = true;
        try {
            cacheConfig.resetProducts();
            String cache = getRequest().getParameter("cacheName");
            CacheManager cm = CacheManager.create();
            if (cache == null || cache.isEmpty() || cache.equalsIgnoreCase("TODOS")) {
                cm.removalAll();
            } else {
                cm.removeCache(cache);
            }
            Print.out("Cache " + cache + " eliminado");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            b = false;
        }
        getRequest().setAttribute("html", b);
        return "html";
    }

    //Methods
}
```

Unfortunately it's a legacy project using Apache Struts so I need call CacheConfig from this struts action. What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: you are calling `resetProducts()` from another class or the same class? Default spring AOP implementation will ignore @CacheEvict if called from the same class.

Comment: I'm calling from another class. I will update my question.

Comment: @SergeyPauk I put cacheEvict in the same class of cacheable annotation (ProductBO) and worked.

Comment: @SergeyPauk can u post it as an answer pls? Solved my problem.